# Structured streaming - Metrics in Grafana

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, graphite, spark-structured-streaming

I am using structured streaming to read data from Kafka and create various aggregate metrics. I have enabled Graphite sink using `metrics.properties`. I have seen applications in older Spark version have streaming related metrics. I don't see streaming related metrics with Structured streaming. What am I doing wrong?

For example - Not able to find Unprocessed Batches or running batches or last completed batch total delay.

I have enabled streaming metrics by setting:

```
SparkSession.builder().config("spark.sql.streaming.metricsEnabled",true)
```

Even then I am getting only 3 metrics:

- driver.spark.streaming.inputrate
- driver.spark.streaming.latency
- driver.spark.streaming.processingrate

These metrics have gaps in between them. Also it starts showing up really late after the application is started. How do I get extensive streaming related metrics to grafana?

I checked `StreamingQueryProgress`. We can only programmatically creating custom metrics using this one. Is there a way I can consume the metrics which Spark streaming already sends to the sink that I mention?

Answer (score 2):

You can still find some of those metrics. The query which actually starts the streaming harness has two methods - [lastProgress](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery@lastProgress:org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryProgress) and [recentProgress](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery@recentProgress:Array%5Borg.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryProgress%5D)

They expose details like number of rows processed, duration of the batch, number of input rows in the batch among other things. There is also a method within called `json` that can get all this information in a single go which can probably be used for sending to some metrics collector.

Comment: Do I find it in graphite where the metrics are sent? I can't find it even after setting spark.sql.streaming.metricsEnabled as true. How do I make sure additional metrics are also sent like the ones you mentioned?

Comment: query.sparkSession.streams.addListener(new StreamingQueryListener() {
      override def onQueryStarted(queryStarted: QueryStartedEvent): Unit = {
        logger.info("Query started: " + queryStarted.id+" for QUERY NAME" +query.name)
      }
      override def onQueryTerminated(queryTerminated: QueryTerminatedEvent): Unit = {
        logger.info("Query terminated: " + queryTerminated.id+" for QUERY NAME" +query.name)
      }
      }
      logger.info("recentProgress"+ query.recentProgress)
      logger.info("progress"+ query.lastProgress)